# PDF of summation of two random variables (different than uniform)

Tags: probability-distributions, summation, random-variables

My question is different than the questions about uniform distribution.

Question: X and Y have the following pdf:

f(x,y) = (1/4)*x*y if 0 < x < 2 and 0 < y < 2

f(x,y) = 0 otherwise

Find the pdf of z = x + y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably intended to use the usual *convolution* procedure. Note that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, with densities $f_X(x)=\frac{x}{2}$ and $f_Y(y)=\frac{y}{2}$, each on the interval $(0,2)$.

But let us instead go back to fundamentals. In the usual coordinate plane, draw the square on which the joint density function of $X$ and $Y$ lives. Let $Z=X+Y$. We find the cumulative distribution function $F_Z(z)$. After we have done that, we can differentiate to get the density function of $Z$.

The cdf of $Z$ is $0$ if $z\le 0$, and $1$ if $z\ge 4$. We now deal with the interesting part, $0\lt z\lt 4$.

It turns out that the calculation is different for $0\lt z\le 2$ than for $2\lt z\lt 4$.

Case (i): We first deal with $0\lt z\le 2$. For fixed $z$ between $0$ and $2$, draw the line $x+y=z$. Then $F_Z(z)$ is the probability of landing below that line. The interesting part of the world below that line is a triangle with corners $(0,0)$, $(z,0)$, and $(0,z)$.  To find $\Pr(Z\le z)$, we integrate the joint density over this triangle. We get
$$F_Z(z)=\int_{x=0}^z \left(\int_{y=0}^{z-x}\frac{1}{4}xy \,dy\right)\,dx.$$
Integrate, and then differentiate with respect to $z$ to get the density $f_Z(z)$. Actually, once we have done the inner integration, we don't need to do the outer one: since we will be differentiating, we can use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. But it may be clearer if we first compute $F_Z(z)$.

Case (ii): Finally, we deal with $2\lt z\lt 4$. Again, this time for a fixed $z$ between $2$ and $4$, draw the line $x+y=z$. Again, $F_Z(z)$ is the probability of ending up below that line. The region of integration is less nice than in Case (i). So it is easier to first find $1-F_Z(z)$, the probability of ending up *above* the line $x+y=z$. Note that $1-F_Z(z)$ is the integral of our joint density over the triangle with corners $(2,z-2)$, $(2,2)$, and $(z-2,2)$. Thus for $2\lt z\lt 4$,
$$1-F_Z(z)=\int_{z-2}^2 \left(\int_{y=z-x}^{2}\frac{1}{4}xy \,dy\right)\,dx.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I totally understand the first case, but I cannot visualize the second one. I see that you calculate 1-F(z) according to the following graph. (http://s22.postimg.org/pgifxq2hd/graph.jpg)

However, I do not understand how z can be between 0 and 2 ? Isn't it supposed to be between 2 and 4?

Comment: I have checked for a typo above, did not see one. Maybe after coffee I will. The picture you linked to is sort of right, except that our original square has corners $(0,0)$, $(2,0)$, $(2,2)$, $(0,2)$. And the diagonal line $x+y=z$ in Case (ii) is above the diagonal of the square, since $z$ is between $2$ and $4$. Integrating over the triangular part of our square above the line gives us $1-F_Z(z)$ when $2\lt z\lt 4$, and from this we can find $f_Z(z)$.

Comment: Thanks again. You say that the picture must be something like this: http://s29.postimg.org/cmzq690lj/graph2.jpg However, the shaded area here seems to be equal to F(z) I guess, not 1-F(z). Also, if this picture is correct, I find the integral limits as x goes from 0 to 2, while y goes from (z-x) to 2. How did you see that the the lower limit of x is (2-z)? And why do you think that the shaded area is equal to 1-F(z)?

Comment: The line should typically be above but parallel to the thick line drawn in the link. The line is for fixed $z$ like $z=2.8$. The shaded area is $1-F_Z(z)$, for $F_Z(z)$ is the probability that $Z\le z$, so it is the integral over the part of the square **below** the line $x+y=z$. Since $x+y=z$, $y$ goes from $z-x$ to $2$.

Comment: OK, but why is that $x$ goes from $2-z$ to $2$? I could understand if it had been $z-2$ to $2$. And why don't we calculate $F_{Z}(z)$ directly? Is it because the shaded area for $F_{Z}(z)$ would be a trapezoid?

Comment: Apologies, that was a "typo" for $z-2$. Yes, the direct calculation is avoided because of the funny shape (not trapezoid). We could integrate over it, but the integral would have to be broken into two parts.

Comment: No apologies. I should be the one to apologize since I ask too many questions :(. If the area for $F_{Z}(z)$ is not a trapezoid, then I could not determine the shaded area corretly. Can you help me to draw that area by writing the corners of the shape ?

Comment: $(0,0)$, $(2,0)$, $(2,z-2)$, $(z-2,2)$, $(0,2)$, a figure with $5$ corners. A trapezoid has $4$.

Comment: Oops! Actually my figure is the same as yours, but I made a mistake by calling it as a trapezoid. Thanks a lot for your help. Now, I can take that integral and find the density.

Comment: You are welcome. Actually, if we replace $X$ and $Y$ by $2-X$ and $2-Y$, there is symmetry, with $Z$ becoming $4-Z$. The symmetry could be used to find the cdf when $2\le Z\le 4$, from the result for $0\le z\le 3$.

Comment: Sorry, but I could not totally understand this approach. I will keep it in mind. Thanks again.